# Linux combine sort files by date created and given file name

Tags: linux, shell, sorting

I need to combine these to commands in order to have a sorted list by date created with the specified "filename".

I know that sorting files by date can be achieved with:

> ls -lrt

and finding a file by name with

> find . -name "filename*"

I don't know how to combine these two. I tried with a pipeline but I don't get the right result.

[EDIT]
Not sorted
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
find . -name "filename" -printf '%TY:%Tm:%Td %TH:%TM %h/%f\n' | sort
```

Forget xargs. "Find" and "sort" are all the tools you need.

Comment: Not sure I agree with the easier, unless you have a working knowledge of the `-printf` format :)

Comment: Well, you're here to learn things, aren't you? I didn't even remember that find has a -printf option until I checked "man find" and noticed it.

Comment: Thank you, awesome

Answer (score 4):

My best guess would be to use `xargs`:

```
find . -name 'filename*' -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/ls -ltr
```

There's an upper limit on the number of arguments, but it shouldn't be a problem unless they occupy more than 32kB (read more [here](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/)), in which case you will get blocks of sorted files :)

Comment: +1: I'm curious how you arrive at 'more than 32k of them'.  I suspect the limit is smaller than that.  IIRC, on Linux, the total size of environment + command line arguments has to be 128 KiB or less, in which case the limit on the file names of length 8 characters each is 16k or so. However, that's cavilling at details, not a major objection.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're right, it should be 32kB (depends on the system but seems a reasonable minimum), not 32000 arguments :)

Comment: exec arg size limit can be found by running `getconf ARG_MAX`

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name "filename" -exec ls --full-time \{\} \; | cut -d' ' -f7- | sort
```

You might have to adjust the cut command depending on what your version of ls outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below-shared command:

1) List Files directory with Last Modified Date/Time
To list files and shows the last modified files at top, we will use -lt options with ls command.

```
$ ls -lt /run
output
total 24
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root utmp 2304 Sep  8 14:58 utmp
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    4 Sep  8 12:41 dhclient-eth0.pid
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root  100 Sep  8 03:31 lock
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   60 Sep  7 23:11 user
drwxr-xr-x.  7 root root  160 Aug 26 14:59 udev
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   60 Aug 21 13:18 tuned
```

https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/how-sort-files-date-using-ls-command-linux/